# css3 for this button

Tags: css

[image]

I have attached the image of the button. On a site I am working with only has this image. It doesn't have PSD or PNG so I am not sure what font-family and size is there. I was asked to create a css that resembles to that image and after several tries and not being designer and css guy I came up with this css3

```
.test
{
  border-top: 1px solid;
   background: #ebebeb;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ebebeb), to(#ebebeb));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #ebebeb);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #ebebeb);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #ebebeb);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #ebebeb);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
   color: #4d4c4d;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
   font-weight:lighter;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the font size and back-ground is still a little off. I thought may be some css3 gurus around here have the answer for me as to what am I missing to have the exact same copy?

here is my copy on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fbpg6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those gradients are doing nothing. Start and end colors are identical.

You're missing a few color declarations in several places as well.

See if [**THIS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Fbpg6/19/) Is closer.

(Note I added margin just to move it away from frame edges.)

Comment: this is very close but the text is too light. thanks

Comment: You can just change the `color:` property to darken the text... update here: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Fbpg6/21/

Answer (score 0):

This closer:

```
.test {
border: 1px solid;
background: #EBEBEB;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EBEBEB), to(#EBEBEB));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB, #EBEBEB);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB, #EBEBEB);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB, #EBEBEB);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB, #EBEBEB);
padding: 7px 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: #ebebeb 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: white 1px 1px 0;
color: #4D4C4D;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
border-image: initial;
border-color: #BBB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches the gradients. You need slightly bigger fonts and different colors to match a PSD to browsers.

```
.test
{
   border: 1px solid #cacaca;
   background-color: #ebebeb;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f0f0f0), to(#e3e3e3));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #ebebeb);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0, #e3e3e3);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0, #e3e3e3);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0, #e3e3e3);
   padding: 5px 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 1px;
   color: #666;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
   font-weight:lighter;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```